# How to validate user input in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I know that the RoR can do the validation in the models. But I want to confirm the user's password in the views. I means, it show two textfield for user to type password twice to ensure the user type the password correct, but in the database I only store one value. How can I handle it in the RoR?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your model do:

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

In your view do:

```
<%= form.password_field :password %>
<%= form.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

This is using the built in rails confirmation validation.  It's will add the virtual accessor for you.

Comment: Wow, that's so sample to do so. Er.... ...One more thing, how can I check all the validation in RoR, is there any document out there? Thx in advance. Xmas.

Comment: You can check api docs online here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html